# Summation problem related to fractional part function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

Let $p$ and $q$ be distinct primes such that $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{q} \left\{\frac{kp}{q} \right\}=51$. Find the unit digit of $q$.

Note that $\{a\}$ signifies the fractional part of $a$.

Comment: What have you tried? Please put your attempts in the body of the question; we will better be able to help you if you do so.

Comment: I tried to apply the property of greatest integer function. i.e {x} = x - [x], where [x] represents greatest integer function and {x} represents fractional part of x.
So, I have rewritten the given expression ∑{pk/q} = ∑pk/q - ∑[pk/q], for k=1 to q. But this doen't lead to any solution. May be some property related to prime numbers would be handful in this case, which I don't have any idea.

Answer (score 5):

Let,

$S = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{q} \left\{\frac{kp}{q} \right\}$

Since the summand is $0$ for $k = 0$ and $k = q$, we get,

$ S = \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{q} \left\{\frac{kp}{q} \right\} $

Change $k$ to $q-k$

$ \displaystyle \implies S = \sum_{k=0}^{q} \left\{p-\frac{kp}{q} \right\} $

$ \displaystyle = \sum_{k=1}^{q-1} \left\{-\frac{kp}{q} \right\} $

Note that,

$ \{x\} + \{-x\} = 1 \ ; \ \forall \ x \notin \mathbb{Z} $

$ \implies S = \displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{q-1} \left(1 - \left\{\frac{kp}{q} \right\}\right) $

$ \implies S = q-1 - S $

$ \implies S = \dfrac{q-1}{2} $

Since $S = 51$

$ \implies q = 103 $

$ \implies q \pmod {10} = 3 $

Comment: As you point out, the value of the summand is $0$ for $k=0,q$ and you use that fact to shift among summation limits as it suits your proof. In the final step, you use summation limits of $1$ and $q-1$. I think your arguments should apply if those limits were $0$ and $q$, which would yield $S=q+1-S$ leading to $q=101$. I can't see a basis to distinguish which set of limits is arguably more appropriate. Can you say why one set of limits is correct or preferred? Note that neither set tracks the summation limits in the posed question, $1$ and $q$, so some change must be made.

Comment: Following on from my previous comment: numerical calculation shows that $q=103$ gives the correct answer (kudos to Robin) and $q=101$ (as well as several other values of $q$ tested as controls) doesn't; that fact does not help me understand why this should be so. I looked at about a dozen values of $p$, most but not all primes, and $q=103$ worked for all I looked at.

Comment: @KeithBackman The equation {x} + {-x} = 1 won't hold throughout the sum if the limits were $0$ and $q$.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me.